# Categorization in Google

Tags: seo

How can I allow such categorization in Google for a website?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of [Sitelinks](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334) in Google search results. According to Google:

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot allow that.

After a while if your website is visited frequently the most important pages will be listed there and you will be able to manage it using the Google Webmaster tool.